# Angular 2 - Дождаться ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular4

Вопрос такой - как сделать, чтобы при выполнении такой функции

```
this._activityService.getActivityAnalyticsCount(this.token, params)
  .map(result => result.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  );
```

Я мог дождаться ответа от сервера и остановить выполнение остальных асинхронных методов.

Просто суть такова - я делаю запрос и пока не прошел ответ, остальные функции не запускаются. Как это реализовать?

Comment: unsubscribe() не вариант ?

Answer (score 1):

переместить остальные асинхронные методы в .subscribe().